# Facebook iframe not loading on my website. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I'm trying to add an iframe to the right hand side of my webpage, but for some reason the iframe won't load when I refresh the page. I tried looking at my developer tools in Google but all I saw was that there was a style property added to my iframe that says,
"display: none !important". I don't know if this is what is keeping it from loading, but that is all I can think of. I looked at other suggestions, but they didn't fix the problem.

I also don't know how to get rid of the display property if it is the issue. I don't have any compiling issues. I'm creating this website with React and I'm trying to display my facebook account with an iframe on the right hand side of my webpage. I could really use some help with this. Here is my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Widgets.css";

function Widgets() {
  return (
    <div className="widgets">
      <iframe 
        title="widgets"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fprofile.php%3Fid%3D100009419984981&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=1500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" 
        width="340" 
        height="1500" 
        scrolling="no" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        style= {{ border: "none", overflow: "hidden" }}
        allow="encrypted-media">
      </iframe>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Widgets;
```

Screenshot of styles affecting the iframe:
[image]

Comment: Try checking whether other internal or external scripts you're using are affecting your iframe, because I've tested and it works without the none display property

Comment: @Cypherjac how do I get rid of the none display property? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried adding this property to the style: `style= {{ border: "none", overflow: "hidden", -> display: 'block !important' <- }}` to try and override the property, since adding a style this way gives it a higher priority than others

Comment: @Cypherjac I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Send a screenshot of the styles affectng the iframe, it's not possible to identify the issue without mmore information

Comment: @Cypherjac the display: "block !important" doesn't override the display none property.

Comment: In your html it seems you've put `display: none !important` as well...

Comment: @Cypherjac I put display: "block !important" inside of my code, but it just keeps showing display: "none !important" every time I refresh the page. I never put display none property in my code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can't really tell your problem because when I recreate it I get different results:

[image]

Link to Codepen here: https://codepen.io/cypherjac/pen/xxpgGLQ `Iframe Codepen`

**That is most likely some external script or style affecting it**

---

I've copy-pasted the exact code from that link you've mentioned and this is what I get..

Check the codepen for the demo

[image: Iframe]

---

As I said, check your styles sources and search for the word iframe to find a style that could be affecting it

Comment: What do you think I should do? I got the facebook iframe from this website: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/ if that helps.

Comment: Check, edited answer ... This is up to you to do some searching on all the styles sources being loaded in your page

Comment: I don't know what you mean by style sources. I already showed you all the styles that I added on my javascript file? Where would style sources be located at?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then I realized Google Chrome is not able to load it, it is heavy. Try Google Incognito, you will see it perfectly working/loading.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32532821)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using iframe for Facebook Embed Post

- If using Normal Chrome iframe, NOT working!
- If using Incognito Mode in Chrome, it works!
- If using Edge, it works!
- If I use my friend's PC chrome, it Works!

** Problem is the chrome cache issue

## Solution

1. Ctrl + Shift + Del  Open the "Clear Browsing Data" in chrome
2. select "Cookies and Other Site Data"
3. select "Cached Images and files"
4. Click "Clear Data"
   [image]
   Follow the setting, then click "Clear Data" which will do.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Firefox.
I installed the extension "Facebook container" a long time ago on my FF. This extension disables interaction with facebook from other sites (ie, it doesn't load the frame).
I just add an exception (in Facebook container) for my site and it works now : I can see my iframe.
This is not a technical response but only some things to check...